# Is there a way to replicate "percentile_cont(x.x) within group (order by col)" from Teradata to BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

I am working on migrating Teradata scripts to BigQuery SQLs. I have a SQL which calculates percentile within a group in Teradata. When migrating to BigQuery, I am not finding a suitable method to replicate this functionality. In BQ docs, it says that the `ORDER BY` clause in not allowed in percentile_cont.

The SQL in Teradata :

```sql
 select 
    unique_id,
    rf_score,
    percentile_cont(0.75) within group (order by col1) as a,
    percentile_cont(0.5)  within group (order by col1) as b,
    percentile_cont(0.25) within group (order by col1) as c
  from
    table t1
    group by 1, 2;
```

The code I am trying in BQ:

```sql
 select 
       unique_id,
       rf_score,
       PERCENTILE_CONT(col1, 0.75) over(ORDER BY col1) as a,
       PERCENTILE_CONT(col1, 0.5)  over(ORDER BY col1) as b,
       PERCENTILE_CONT(col1, 0.25)  over(ORDER BY col1) as c
 from
    table t1
    group by 1, 2;
```

I am pretty new to BQ. I have tried few different combinations of window partitioning but nothing works. Not able to think of any workaround for this issue. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Provide sample data and desired output. You may refer to this post on [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my understanding, `PERCENTILE_CONT` in BigQuery doesn't require `ORDER BY`.
It'll calculate percentiles over sorted values internally.

And you look want to use this. (I'm not familiar with Teradata):

```sql
       PERCENTILE_CONT(col1, 0.75) OVER (PARTITION BY unique_id, rf_score) as a,
       PERCENTILE_CONT(col1, 0.5)  OVER (PARTITION BY unique_id, rf_score) as b,
       PERCENTILE_CONT(col1, 0.25) OVER (PARTITION BY unique_id, rf_score) as c
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It works. PERCENTILE_CONT does sort values internally.